Can my Spring Boot backend app determine which CDN proxy server is the closest to a client?
I have a Spring Boot backend app which is hosted in my linux server as a docker container.
I have a case when a user visit my website and open product's catalog. Product's catalogs contains a lot of pictures.

The user's browser send the http request to the backend server to get all needed data for this product's catalog web page.
Backend got this http request from the frontend (user's browser),
handles this request (In the backend side, data is retrieved from the database (Postgresql in my case)).
Then backend returns the http response in the form of a json
which contains info about each product in this product's catalog,
including the link the product's picture (for example
http://cdn.example.com/images/product1.jpg).
The frontend uses this url address http://cdn.example.com/images/product1.jpg to download the product's picture.
On this step DNS Lookup happens. DNS tries to determine the particular physical address which relates to this domain name http://cdn.example.com/images/product1.jpg.

Well, what happens next? Here my understanding is poor.
I just heard that backend can store some data about user in a database to determine which CDN proxy server is the closest to a client.
I would like to know how my Spring Boot backend app can do this task? or it should be done by other part of the system?

Your SpringBoot application should be independent of which CDN returns back the image to the customer. You should only be returning the valid URL. Then it is CDN's responsibility (based on its configuration) to return that image to the customer from his nearest location.

CDN will get the IP of the browser and its geographic location and will check which CDN server is nearest to the customer's location and then service the image from that location - for this the request would NEVER come to your backend server. And it should not also. If that is done by your server, then what's the point in having a CDN near to the browser - the request always comes to your backend server.

This is often done at the DNS level. When your browser resolves the CDN address the smart nameserver handling the resolution returns the CDNs IP address that is closest to the geo-location of the browser's IP address.

I believe it is important to explicitly separate "the nearest CDN node" and "the nearest backend API" problems.
The main idea behind CDN is that to make our system more reliable and performant for distributed loading, we introduce a distributed proxy & cache that hides the original application (CDN edge-node). In doing that, we add a DNS record that points to the IP addresses of CDN edge-node. Urls with this domain might be stored. Under the hood, a CDN proxy node requests to our origin server and caches results. If an origin server outage is in place, our static data might still work due to edge-caching. So, the next question is how to find the best (the closest) CDN edge-node?
Anycast DNS
Anycast DNS is a traffic routing algorithm that allows to assign one IP address to many nodes. The approach has helpful advantages:

high availability, thanks to multiple nodes with redundancy sharing the same IP address
lower latency because traffic is routed to the geographically nearest server
scaling via adding new nodes

Ok, our closest CDN node has the same IP and the router will choose it as the closest one because of Anycast. This is still unclear how does this guarantee we do not go across the world to find the closest node? IXP will help us to answer how to avoid The Trombone Effect (inefficient network path of queries).
IXP
Internet Exchange Point (IXP) is a physical location. Internet Service Providers and CDN providers share infrastructure there to establish the most efficient cross-network communication. IXP is presented as one or more physical buildings and depending on a particular demand it is helpful to connect networks either for free or some members might charge for their service. So, CDN has its edge node in the closest to a particular client IXP which is well-connected with other networks and especially with CDN providers. A map of IXP can be found right there.
https://www.internetexchangemap.com/
So, let's imagine that we have CDN with pictures and get them efficiently but there is another problem with finding the nearest backend API for a particular client which returns meta-data for your pictures. GeoDNS comes to the stage. For the same domain of your API server, GeoDNS will return different IP addresses depending on client's IP, so your server in Germany will handle the request from a users from France only because GeoDNS server decided that France is closer than the USA.
Summing this up, your spring boot application does not decide who is the nearest to your client. It is rather a combination of IXP + installed CDN nodes + Anycast DNS caching your regular responses and GeoDNS for custom server APIs
Worth reading:
https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-anycast-dns
